# How can I use sessions with the client ip changing every 5 minutes?

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, ip-address

I'm working on a web application that currently uses a Session to hold the userid and privileges. This is causing a problem for me because the client ip address changes normally every 5 minutes, sometimes faster, so the sessions are lost.

My current work around is to encrypt a string the will auto-login when the session dies, but it still causes issues because forms will not be submitted if the auto-login process has to be run.

I can post some code, but I feel that I'm way off base with my current method of attack. Can I please get some suggestions?

Thank you!

The webapp is for about 10 users and if possible, I'd like it to never timeout so that if they are looking at a page for 4 days and come back to it, they can press submit and it submits.

Comment: client ip address changes *shouldn't* affect sessions, if you're using the built in support - the session identifiers are held in a cookie or url, and neither is tied to the client ip address. So what are you doing that's tying it in this fashion?

Comment: In simple form just this 'Session("User") = "Data" and that seems to be lost when the IP changes

Comment: You'll lose the session if you're using `InProc` session state and the *application pool* recycles, but that's a server side issue (and rather worrying if that's happening every 5 minutes). The default session timeout is 20 minutes.

Comment: Honestly, there is no senstive data being stored on this webapp, I'm almost thinking about just storing the USERID in a cookie and calling from that and not working with sessions at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're losing session after 5 minutes, or why it appears to be correlated with client IP address changes (is this an intranet app? Does something else happen on 5 minute intervals?).

The following `web.config` [setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx) should create sessions that last for 6 months, and will survive application pool recycles:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" timeout="262800"
    stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"/>
```

Of course, you'll have to have the state server running on your machine, and everything stored in the session will need to be serializable.

---

As Jarrett points out, it's rather odd to want to keep sessions alive for so long with no activity, and I wouldn't recommend it if there was going to be a significant number of users, but if it really is 10 and only 10 users, it's probably okay.

Comment: All I get when changing the web.config is "Unable to serialize the session state."

Comment: Right, so you're actually storing more complex data in the session than just the strings you gave as an example, and for some reason, your application pool is recycling *very* frequently - that's the underlying issue. By default, the app pool should only recycle every 29 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the page to stay valid for four days, don't use Session and don't use Viewstate. You can store data in cookies, on the page in hidden input fields and in the URL querystring. Nothing else is going to be reliable over that span of time. If you are storing sensitive or security dependent information, do it responsibly, that is probably its own question.